# Infimum and supremum of the set $\{(\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}):n\in \mathbb{N}\} $ with dictionary order in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Geometrically thinking, it goes from $(1,0)$ and approaches $(0,1)$.

So, my guess is infimum is $(0,1)$ and supremum is $(1,0)$.

Is it true? can someone help?

Comment: $(0,1) < (1,0)$

Comment: yes I am sorry typing mistake

Comment: Isn't $(0,a) \leq (\frac 1n , 1 - \frac 1n)$ for every $n$ in the dictionary order,  by looking at the first coordinate? So there's no infimum, likewise no supremum.

Comment: ohhh yes, there is no supremum, but (1,0) is in the set, How do you say that it is not supremum

Comment: $(1,-1)$ is a smaller upperbound.

Comment: No one ever said $\mathbb R^2$ with the dictionary order has the least upper bound property.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  Not it isn't.  $(1,-1) < (\frac 11, 1-\frac 11)$ so it is not an upper bound. I think the OP is right that $(1,0)$ is an upper bound, and as it is in the set there can't be any lower upper bound.

Comment: The problem with saying it "approaches $(0,1)$" is that if $\frac 1n$ approaches *but is always more than* $0$ it doesn't matter that that $1-\frac 1n$ approaches $1$.  So long as $\frac 1n > 0$ the first terms of $(\frac 1n, 1-\frac 1n)$ and the first term of $(0,x)$ are the *ONLY* things that determine the relation and $1-\frac 1n$ being close to $1$  is no more relevant that $1-\frac 1n$ being a 5 thousan miles from a googolplex.  And actually $(0, 10^{10^{100}})$ *is* closer to $(0.0001, 0.9999)$ than $(0,1)$ is [because $(0,1) < 0, 10^{10^{100}})< (0.0001, 0.9999)$].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for any $n\in \mathbb N$ we have $\frac 1n > 0$ so any $(0,x) < (\frac 1n,1-\frac 1n)$ so any $(0, x)$ is lower bound.

If $k > 0$ then there is an $n \in \mathbb N$ so that $0< \frac 1n < k$ so $(\frac 1n,1-\frac 1n) < (k,x)$ so no $(k,x);k \ge 0$ can be and lower bound.

(And it pretty much goes without saying, but for the sake of being thorough, if $k < 0$ then $(k,x) < (0,y)$ for all $x,y$. So, although all $(k,x)$ are all lower bounds to our set, none of them are *greatest* lower bounds, as $(0,y)$ are all lower bounds that are higher.)

So *if* any $\inf$ of the set exists is of the form $(0,x)$.  But for every $(0,x)$ that is a lower bound there is a $y>x$ so that $(0,y)> (0,x)$ but $(0,y)$ is also a lower bound.  So there is no $\inf$ of the set.

.....

If $n \in \mathbb N$ then either $n =1$ and $(\frac 1n, 1-\frac 1n) = (1,0)$ or $n > 1$ and $(\frac 1n, 1-\frac 1n) < (1,0)$.  So $(1,0) \ge (\frac 1n, 1-\frac 1n)$ for all elements in the set.  So $(1,0)$ is an upper bound.

But $(1,0) = (\frac 11, 1-\frac 11)$ is in the set.

So if $(x,y) < (1,0)$ then $(x,y)$ can not be an upper bound (because $(1,0)$ is an element that is larger than $(x,y)$.).  So $(1,0)$ is the $\sup$ of the set..

===

Addendum:  Don't forget the actual definition and a *very* basic test for $\inf$ and $\sup$ is that the $\sup$ ($\inf$) is a upper (lower) bound so that any element that is less (greater) than it is *not* an upper (lower) bound.

So as every $(0,x)$ *does* have a $(0, y) $ greater than it that is a lower bound, no $(0,x)$ can be an $\inf$.  And as nothing lower than $(1,0)$ can be an upper bound while $(1,0)$ then $(1,0)$ is $\sup$.

Answer (score 2):

Any point $(0,x)$ is a lower bound, and to be a lower bound for the set, the first coordinate has to be $\le 0$ (if $(a,b)$ with $a>0$ then for large $n$, $\frac1n < a$ and $(\frac1n, 1-\frac1n) <  (a,b)$ and so no lower bound).

So there is no greatest lower bound (aka infimum) ($(0,b)$ is always smaller than $(0,b+1)$ etc.)

As to upperbounds, $(1,0)$ is the maximum of the set (take $n=1$) and thus it’s supremum too.

Comment: "Likewise all points like (1,x) are upperbounds"  How so.  $(1,0) = (\frac 1n, 1-\frac 1n)$ where $n=1$ so  $(1,x); x < 0$ is not an upper bound.  But $(1,0)$ and $(1,x); x> 0$ are.  but nothing less than $(1,0)$ is. So $(1,0)$ is the supremum,  isn't it?

Comment: @fleablood you’re right. I wasn’t thinking. Edited.